# HTML Variables for Recurring Payments Buttons with a modifier

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm looking to add a modifier to my PayPal Subscription button. I'd like to modify the subscription cost depending upon how many users the customer enters. Essentially, the subscribe button has a "base cost", with +$xx.xx added to the monthly subscription cost.

For example:

A user wants to create an account on my app with 6 users at $5 per user with a base subscription cost of $10/mo. The monthly cost of that subscription would be $40.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved(may not be the most optimal solution)
Go to [PayPal button designer](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer)
[image]

Moreover you are an advanced user in PayPal, you can customize checkout pages for your customers, streamline checkout, and more in this section.

Comment: I've looked into this. As far as I'm aware, you can't use the Textbox to modify the monthly subscription cost. The textbox is just a "message" sent to the seller. Like you were going to engrave a message on something.

Comment: there is a third section to this.. which deals with with how to customize checkout..
and you can provide different values using options only in case they are restricted(? though I don't think so)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to build the markup as such. Then, using JavaScript I was able to assign the .val() of the item_number, item_name, and a3 fields. Works great!

```html
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display: inline-block">

  <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="...">

  <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
  <!-- Identify the subscription. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" monthly_item_name>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" monthly_item_name>

  <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="monthly">
  <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

  <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

  <!-- Send the user back here once they've completed payment. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[ID]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="...">
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Monthly" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```